# 3d curve macro recording not working in catia vba

Tags: vba, macros, recorder, catia

i have been trying to record the creation of a 3d curve using control points in catia using the macro recorder but it refuses to record anything except part.update. I even tried it in both Freestyle workbench and Digitized shape editor workbench, but both have same result. please could someone explain to me how to do it or atleast where i could find such macro

Answer (score 0):

The Freestyle 3D curve is not supported by automation (there is no API). Nor are any of the tools in DSE. That is why, in this case, nothing is recorded.

Also, sometimes recording doesn't work even when APIs which do exist.